# Select rows 1 week before of a timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

There is an INT field which I store timestamps in table.

I am trying to select rows 1 week before this timestamp

```
WHERE last_loc_date > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: No pictures thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `unix_timestamp` to calculate second argument:

```
WHERE last_loc_date > unix_timestamp(DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Please avoid using `FROM_UNIXTIME(last_loc_date) >  DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK`. This condition is [not SARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) unless you use function-based index.

Comment: "This condition is not SARGable" About time that MySQL supports native expression/functions indexing like PostgreSQL does.. No more need to simulate it with generated columns

Comment: @RaymondNijland Great, but still user has to create function index. If possible we should avoid such constructs.

Comment: "but still user has to create function index. If possible we should avoid such constructs" Great the user needs to create a index annyway also for this query.. Or the user creates a t-bree index or a expression/functions index it doesn't matter in mine opinion

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've assumed that this index may exists. As a rule of thumb - create objects that support as many scenarios as possible. Anway could you provide link to doc where it states that MySQL 8.0 supports expression in indexes?

Comment: "Anway could you provide link to doc where it states that MySQL 8.0 supports expression in indexes?" Generated column indexing is MySQL 5.7+ not MySQL 8.0..  "Generated columns can simulate functional indexes: Use a stored column to define a functional expression and index it." source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html  Also can index JSON data  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ok, I know that workaround. I thought I could make it directly as in PostgreSQL/Oracle `CRATE INDEX idx ON tab(UPPPER(col))`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use DATE(now()) if you want respect the strictly one week

```
WHERE last_loc_date > unix_timestamp(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```